# How to include negative values in y-axis with matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So, I'm making a scatter plot, and one of my data columns has lot of negative values. That is my y-axis.
However when I plot it starts my axes from 0. How do I make it start from the actual lowest value?
[image: My Chart]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `plt.ylim()`, along with the built-in `min()` and `max()` functions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [38, -21, 37, 54, 10, 10, -40, -37, -24, 53, -10, 45, -32, -37, 12, -29, 18, 5, -45, 19, 48, 48, 27, -10, -17, -15, -25, -44, 41, -8]
y = [31, -43, -3, 18, -48, 4, -54, -34, -42, 13, 31, -4, 17, 3, 16, -30, -23, -27, -9, 13, -40, 13, 0, -41, 5, -26, 16, -9, 40, 16]

plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Zelix75 Yep :) Just add `plt.xlim(min(x), max(x))` right above the `plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))`.

Comment: Worked, however, I had to make min arg of ylim = -10, as otherwise there was no visible difference

Comment: @Zelix75 Oh, good! Some people prefer to have padding around the boundaries, so `plt.ylim(min(y), max(y))` caould be `plt.ylim(min(y) - 10, max(y) + 10)`.

Comment: How do I set a defined scale for my y axis?. Like, I wanna change it to 5 or something

Comment: @Zelix75 Use `pot.yticks()` with `range`, third parameter of the `range` is the scale: `plt.yticks(range(min(y), max(y), 5))`

Comment: So should I remove plt.ylim?

Comment: @Zelix75 You can,

Comment: It says 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @Zelix75 Use `plt.yticks(range(round(min(y)), round(max(y)), 5))` then.

Answer (score 3):

Set your limit.
For example : `plt.ylim(-5, 5)`

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution might be `matplotlib.pyplot.ylim()`. Get your lowest `y` value and pass it into this to set it as your lowest `y` axis value.

Something like `matplotlib.pyplot.ylim(bottom= np.min(y_array))`.

See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html for more details.